# Using Regex to find certain file types

Tags: regex, linux, bash

Having issues trying to copy just `jpg`,`png` & `JPG` files starting with `IMG_0000` from one directory to another. I have found the correct expression but I am struggling to make it work.

Below I have put the correct Regex as well as my code so far. The directory I am copying from is `/root/memory` and the target directory is `/root/photoarch`. Please note that inside `/root/memory` there are multiple sub-directories and multiple different file types.

Regex:

```
IMG_[0-9]{4}.[jpg,png,JPG]{3}
```

Code:

```
#!bin/bash
mkdir photoarch
find "/root/memory" -regex '.*IMG_[0-9]{4}.[jpg,png,JPG]{3}' -exec cp {} "/root/photoarch"\;
```

Comment: `[]` is a set of characters to look for, which means `[jpg,png,JPG]{3}` is looking for 3 characters in the set, so this will match any combination of the characters `jJpPngG,`. You need to use a group instead such as `(?:jpg|png|JPG)`. You should probably use `(?:[jJ][pP][eE]?[gG]|[pP][nN][gG])` or `(?i)(?:jpe?g|png)(?-i)` (assuming bash allows this) instead. If you don't care about `IMG` being uppercase (you're ok with a case-insensitive search), simply use the case-insensitive flag (typically `i`) and `(?:jpe?g|png)`.

Comment: @ctwheels It's not bash which interprets that regex. It's `find`.

Comment: Joe: A clearer problem statement would be useful. What is happening and how does it differ from your expectations?

Comment: You need to tell `find` how to interpret that regex by adding `-regextype posix-egrep` to the `find` command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to copy files named `IMG_<4-digits>.<jpg|JPG|png>`, then your regular expression is wrong, as well as its type (by default `find` uses Emacs RE, not [POSIX ERE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_04)).

Regarding the regular expression, you'll have to use [alternation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_04_07) instead of character range. For example `jpg|png` will match either `jpg` or `png`. In contrast, `[jpg,png]{3}` will match any 3-character sequence of `j` or `p` or `g` or `,` or `n`, like `jjj`, `j,p`, and `pnj`. Also, you'll have to escape the dot (with `\.`), otherwise it will match any character.

To use POSIX ERE, set `-regextype` to `posix-extended` (to list all types accepted, run `find -regextype help`).

For case-insensitive matching, you can use `-iregex`.

```
find /root/memory -regextype posix-extended -iregex '.*img_[0-9]{4}\.(jpg|png)' -exec cp {} /root/photoarch \;
```

(The parentheses around `jpg|png` are necessary because concatenation has higher priority than alternation.)

Comment: Both the original authors and your RE don't match his textual description; he says `begin with IMG_0000`, but then searches for `img_[0-9]{4}` which means (assuming all images do indeed have 4 zeroes and then some digits in their name) will never match.

Comment: I'm assuming OP wants to match `IMG_<4-digits>.<ext>` (see my first sentence).

Comment: Yeah thanks randomir, this is exactly what I was looking for. Apologies for the poorly worded question as you can see im quite new to stack overflow!

Comment: @JoeBloggs, you're welcome, glad to help. And welcome to SO! :)